# How to make a delay in processing project?

Tags: java, processing, delay

I'm using Java within a [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)) project. I'm trying to make a delay that doesn't stop the program, but stops only a given block of code. That "processing" block of code could for example add 1 to a variable, then wait one second and then add 1 again. The problem is that `delay()` (see [reference](https://processing.org/reference/delay_.html)) stops the whole program and `Thread.sleep()` doesn't work in a Processing project.

Comment: Processing is running with a main loop, right? You could simply get the timestamp at the start. Then, whenever you need the value of that counter (that, as you said, should be increased by 1 every second), you check the timestamp again and can easily calculate how many seconds have passed (= your counter).

Comment: How would I do that I am new to java and I just started on monday.

Comment: With [`Timestamp.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) - not sure if that works in Processing, but I guess it would as Processing is just Java after all?

Comment: And otherwise you could use the time & data functions provided by Processing, see the [reference](https://processing.org/reference/)

Comment: What's stopping you from creating a new thread and executing the delay() there ? https://processing.org/reference/thread_.html

Comment: what import would I use for the timestamp

Comment: A "funny" way I have done this is creating a method `myDelay()` that runs a `for` loop (with a relatively big number) that does no operation at all, thus, just delaying the execution.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `delay()` or `Thread.sleep()` in Processing unless you're already using your own threads. Don't use it on the default Processing thread (so don't use it in any of the Processing functions).

Instead, use the `frameCount` variable or the `millis()` function to get the time that your event starts, and then check that against the current time to determine when to stop the event.

Here's an example that shows a circle for 5 seconds whenever the user clicks:

```
int clickTime = 0;
boolean showCircle = false;

void draw(){
  background(64);
  if(showCircle){
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, width, height);

    if(clickTime + 5*1000 < millis()){
      showCircle = false;
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  clickTime = millis();
  showCircle = true;
}
```

Side note: please try to use proper punctuation when you type. Right now your question is just one long run-on sentence, which makes it very hard to read.